# display categories using php in worpdress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

How to display wordpress categories with images using php code?
i tried this :

```
 <?php get_the_category_list( $separator, $parents, $post_id ); ?>
```

but it just lists categories without images. , i want to list categories with there images like when we list products

thanks

Comment: have you setup images for each category?

Comment: yes i added categories thumbnails

Comment: fetch them in the way you have stored them in db.... and use get_terms instead

Comment: can you show me, don't know how

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` in you code for getting category image.